# Substitution on a Graph

Tags: graphing-functions, substitution

Let's say we have the equation $y = \tan(x)$.

We can break this into $y = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$.

Let's say we wanted $a = \sin(x)$.

Therefore, $y = \frac{a}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}$.

However, if I graph the new function y(a) instead of y(x), if looks very different. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks different because $a$ and $x$ (the things you're plotting on the x asis) are different quantities.

If instead you plotted $y(a(x)) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}}$ you would get the same graph as $y = \tan(x).$

Also if you plotted $\tan(x)$ versus $\sin(x)$ (instead of vs x) you would get the graph of $\frac{a}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}$